# Activate the OCI8/Oracle extension for PHP - ERROR (not found)

Tags: php, macos, operating-system, xampp

I've just installed XAMPP on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

I wrote a PHP page in Netbeans and when I try to run it I get
Object not found!

When checking the status in XAMPP it says PHP extension is deactivated, so I followed the steps to activate it and when I opened the terminal and ran:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lampp oci8
```

I got

```
sudo: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lampp: command not found
```

I don't know how to fix this or activate it. Please can you help, as specifically as possible, because I am new to this.

Comment: anyone have an idea? bump

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp oci8

lampp -> xampp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/xampp/oci8install`